# Firebase deploy cloud functions suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am very confused. I've had no problems at all for a long time, and now I suddenly can't deploy anymore. I can't remember doing anything that could have caused this.

I have 3 different cloud functions. When I ran `firebase deploy` I got what seemed to be the same error for each one:

```
!  functions[generateThumbs(europe-west1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/sharp-261f9e9e/docs/image'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/firebase-admin-a1197e24/lib/auth/token-verifier.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@types/lodash-973f4ada/common/math.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/sharp-261f9e9e/docs/index.md'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@types/lodash-973f4ada/common/number.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@types/lodash-973f4ada/common/object.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@google-cloud/storage-66ff4fa1/build/src/channel.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@google-cloud/storage-66ff4fa1/build/src/channel.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/express-5648fc3a/index.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@google-cloud/storage-66ff4fa1/build/src/file.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/express-5648fc3a/LICENSE'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/tar-253f970f/lib/update.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/express-5648fc3a/Readme.md'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/tar-253f970f/lib/warn-mixin.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file
or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/tar-253f970f/lib/winchars.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/tar-253f970f/lib/write-entry.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/xregexp-5f45e5d3/MIT-LICENSE.txt'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/ast-types-c8750e07/gen/namedTypes.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/ast-types-c8750e07/gen/nodes.d.ts'\nnpm ERR! code E404\nnpm ERR! 404 Not Found: websocket-driver@0.7.2\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-06-21T23_38_41_651Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "1A98E1A1"}}
```

I googled, and someone said to delete `package-lock.json`, so i did. I ran `npm install` and it gave me these warnings:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\node_modules\concat-stream\node_modules\isarray\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions\node_modules\ms\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Jesper\intergun\functions\node_modules\through2\node_modules\isarray\package.json'
```

Then i tried `firebase deploy --only functions`, and I got this error for each cloud function:

```
!  functions[generateThumbs(europe-west1)]: Deployment error.
Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-06-21T23_51_11_275Z-debug.log\n\nerror: `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "70391B03"}}
```

Why is this suddenly happening, and what can I do to fix it? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error messages are saying there are things missing in your node_modules folder.  Delete the entire node_modules folder, then npm install again.

Comment: My bad, should have tried that first. It worked. I wonder how those things got removed from my `node_modules`, though. Oh well..

Comment: This worked. I had the exact same problem, the only difference being I am using `yarn`. However I'm not sure why this would be related to my local machine. I hadn't made any change at all. I found a thread (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1015) showing a similar problem caused due to a version bump in `firebase-tools` previously. Could the root cause and solution be something else?

Comment: Whoaaa! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very stupid, hard-to-debug error. The logging is cryptographic if you have many functions.

Try any of the following:

- Using **node 8** instead of **node 10** (though recently fixed internally, I have found there are still issues with node 10)
- Check for possible corrupted or recently-installed dependencies, and remove
- Nuking `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and running npm install

For me, it was the first option that got things in motion again. I also re-initialised firebase, reinstall firebase-tools and tried different node versions, though I don't think these steps made any difference.

Answer (score 0):

On your functions directory, install both firebase-functions and then firebase-admin.

npm install firebase-functions
then 
npm install firebase-admin

Then deploy your functions
firebase deploy --only functions